# sequelize converting where clause into and clause while joining two tables

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two tables `Coupons` and `LocationCoupons`.

```
Coupons
--------------
id

LocationCoupons
----------------
id
coupon_id
location_id
```

I want to select all those record from `Coupons` which doesn't exist in `LocationCoupons`.

I am able to get desired result by writing raw queries like below.

```
const [results, metadata] = await sequelize.query("
    SELECT c.id, c.coupon_code FROM coupons c 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT l.id FROM location_coupon_map l WHERE c.id = l.coupon_id)");
```

But when I try to do the same with association, using joins, passed `where` clause is being converted `and`.

```
const coupons = await Coupon.findAll({
            include: {
                model: LocationCoupon,
                where: {
                    coupon_id: null
                },
                required: false,
                attributes: []
            },
            attributes: ["id", "coupon_code"]
        })
```

Above association is generating below query.

```
SELECT `Coupon`.`id`, `Coupon`.`coupon_code` FROM `coupons` AS `Coupon` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `location_coupon_map` AS `LocationCoupons` 
ON `Coupon`.`id` = `LocationCoupons`.`coupon_id` 
AND `LocationCoupons`.`coupon_id` IS NULL;
```

While it should be.

```
SELECT `Coupon`.`id`, `Coupon`.`coupon_code` FROM `coupons` AS `Coupon` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `location_coupon_map` AS `LocationCoupons` 
ON `Coupon`.`id` = `LocationCoupons`.`coupon_id` 
WHERE `LocationCoupons`.`coupon_id` IS NULL;
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Sequelize docs are not that good. They should have described better all the possible queries with associations.

```
 const coupons = await Coupon.findAll({
            where: {
                "$LocationCoupons.coupon_id$": null
            },
            include: {
                model: LocationCoupon,
                attributes: []
            },
            attributes: ["id", "coupon_code"]
        })
```

Now generated query and result is as desired.

```
SELECT `Coupon`.`id`, `Coupon`.`coupon_code` FROM `coupons` AS `Coupon` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `location_coupon_map` AS `LocationCoupons` 
ON `Coupon`.`id` = `LocationCoupons`.`coupon_id` 
WHERE `LocationCoupons`.`coupon_id` IS NULL;
```

Comment: "You can accept your own answer in 2 days" that's what I am getting.

Comment: Ok - fair enough